# Django ORM update with unique=True

Tags: django, validation, orm, sql-update, unique-constraint

An XML file is read in and the database updated with the new information. After validating the XML data, and before updating/saving a specific record, it is reasonable to compare the new data to the database record.

The desire is to use an object oriented approach. What is the best way to accomplish this task?

A sketch of the model is given below. Note that the unique field is set true and this places restrictions on creating instances of Client objects.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

class Client(BaseModel):

employee_id = models.CharField(max_length = 30, primary_key = True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, null=False, blank=False)

class Alias(BaseModel):

client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='aliases')
ssn = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
driver_lic = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

Comment: What comparison were you hoping to make? Just that the two entries (SSN and driver license) are indeed unique or something else as well?

Comment: It is possible that the SSN in the XML file is validated, however it is different from the SSN in the database. On comparing the two numbers before updating an entry could be written to a log file flagging a possible data error.

Comment: Could you lay out which fields are being used to match XML entries to database entries (if any) and which are available to be updated in the database from the XML entry?

Comment: db.aliases.scheme = 'SSN' and db.aliases.value = '000-00-0000'

xml.aliases.scheme = 'SSN' and xml.aliases.value = '111-11-1111'

Comment: This isn't a problem because '111-11-1111' is unique. If on the other hand the xml data had '000-00-0000' I would not be able to create the xml Client object because of the unique=True.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for something like get_or_create() which will retrieve an object from the db if it matches certain fields, otherwise will create a new object with those values. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create for more details. Is that getting at your question?

Comment: So I can "create" an image of the database object based upon the XML data for comparison with the Aliases defined as a Client object.. When I try to "get" the database object from MySQL it gives me an error due to the unique=True field set for the Alias class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to the problem:

Save the XML book to a separate database. The approach starts in the settings.py file where a second database is created. There is limited support for a multiple database admin page.

Are there any other approaches?